# Does A Song of Ice and Fire need individual book tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking through some tags I came across

- [a-clash-of-kings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-clash-of-kings) - 1 question
- [a-storm-of-swords](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-storm-of-swords) - 16 questions

but did not see

- [a-game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-game-of-thrones)
- [a-feast-for-crows](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-feast-for-crows)
- [a-dance-with-dragons](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-dance-with-dragons)
- [the-winds-of-winter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-winds-of-winter)
- [a-dream-of-spring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-dream-of-spring)

Also, I have noticed that some series (Star Wars is the prime example) will get tags for each installation in the series while other (Harry Potter comes to mind) do not.

**This question is directly related to A Song of Ice and Fire... do we need/want tags for each book?**

Judging by the inconstant and low usage of the current two tags, my opinion would be that: No, we do not need them. The tag [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) should be able to cover the series.

We also have the issue of the TV show (and tag to accompany it) [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) to cause endless confusion.

However, I do ask the question because I have seen this type of editing done. Whether it was out necessity, trying to bring old questions to the surface again, or an attempt to get one of our many coveted badges is not known to me.

In addition, I would be willing to undertake the grunt work either way to adding/removing tags if a consensus could be made.

Comment: Related post on why Harry Potter doesn't have tags for each book: [Why don't we have tags for each Harry Potter installment?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8132) CreationEdge's answer is helpful and probably relevant here somehow.

Comment: I think Star Wars: The Force Awakens needed a tag because we expected a lot of incoming questions quickly (it was a high-profile movie released recently) and some people wanted to avoid spoilers for a while.

Comment: @b_jonas could the same be said for Winds of Winter? When it finally get released anyway?

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, no.

Comment: @Kevin Being newer to Stack , what would be the course of action? Remove the existing tags? or just let it ride as is?

Comment: @Skooba Editing by hand, [tag:a-clash-of-kings] is easy to remove and [tag:a-storm-of-swords] could be done over the course of a few days. Alternatively, a mod could merge both tags into the [tag:a-song-of-ice-and-fire] tag. (By contrast, note that adding new tags for all the individual books would have to be done by hand and would take much longer and involve much more editing - unless we decided to use these tags going forward and not apply them retrospectively, I suppose, but I can't abide inconsistency.)

Comment: @armadillo Yes, and after some teeth-grinding I've learned to cope with it ;-)

Comment: Inconsistency is evil @Randal'Thor :)

Comment: Should "accompy" be "accompany"?

Comment: A little late to this but also relevant. Individual movie tags in the [Marvel Cinematic Universe](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9640/marvel-cinematic-universe-movie-titles-that-have-the-same-name-as-the-superhero)
And [how do we use tags?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7877/how-do-we-actually-use-tags?lq=1) A: Inconsistently

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, we don't need tags for each book.

I say this for purely pragmatic reasons: out of the 675 [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) questions, 662 of them are not tagged with any book in the series. For the most part, people on the site have managed just fine without tags for these books.

If we want tags for each book, then to make our tagging consistent, someone would have to review all 662 of those questions to see if any of them should have a book tag. On the other hand, if a mod merges the two existing book tags into [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire), our tagging will be consistent, with no edits required for any question.

**I suggest merging the existing book tags into the series tag.**

Comment: Maybe back then, but generally we haven't used than convention and it's been fine. Wheel of Time, Sword of Truth, etc. Sometimes movies if they have special significance, like Star Wars. Served us fine

Comment: Agreed. In addition to this, a lot of the ASOIAF questions I've seen are asking about non-book specific things. How many Valyrian  swords exist, who would succeed Tommen, etc. So I question how many of those 600+ questions actually would use the new tag system.

Comment: The one place that it would potentially be useful would be TWoW for spoilers, but it's probably not worth changing tags for that situation

Answer (score -2):

Yes, I would think that each book needs a tag of its own.

- While there is an overall plot, each book does in fact have special things that happen in it that need clarification.
- General tags are confusing because like with Game of Thrones, TV show questions get thrown in with novel-based questions and the mix is a muddle.

Just my five cents worth. But I like having a place to put things that are organized :)

Comment: Also, how would you distinguish between questions about the Game of Thrones TV show and those about the Game of Thrones book in the A Song of Ice and Fire series?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well maybe something like the Marvel tags? There is [tag:marvel-cinematic-universe] and then there is just [tag:marvel-comics].  So what about Game of Thrones TV (or something) and A Song Of Ice and Fire Novels? The exact wording would need to be discussed but....

Comment: @armadillo I don't know... That would depend on how the new tag system (if there is one) is implemented and if it applies only to new questions coming in or if it is all mods on deck.

Comment: @armadillo For the Game of Throne Books... The OP's question of "Should we or shouldn't we add tags for the individual books"?

Comment: Like I know how this site well enough to suggest a new tagging system?! I am just dabbling my toes into the "shallow" end of the pool here to learn more about the site and while one can learn a lot by lurking joining in a *little* bit is often the best away... But not ready to be set a task like that! :)

Comment: We are in the same boat then!! :)

Comment: @Rand Personally, I think it'd be fine to append GoT with "-tv" regardless, but qi don't know if tag misuse is a problem. If it's not by now, it probably won't be.

Comment: @Rincewind There's no problem distinguishing between the GoT and aSoIaF tags at the moment. We use [tag:game-of-thrones] for the TV series and [tag:a-song-of-ice-and-fire] for the book series, and AFAIK these questions are rarely mistagged. What I was talking about was the confusion that would arise from having a [tag:game-of-thrones] tag for the TV show and an [tag:a-game-of-thrones] tag for the first book in the series.

Comment: @CreationEdge See above - there's no problem at the moment, but there might be if we introduced individual-book tags.

Comment: @Rand Woah, didn't see all those comments! Yes, those tags would complicate things and take up space, as we'd still need the franchise tag.

Comment: @Randal'Thor AH! The light has dawned! Well that would be an A little complex to fix. What about adding tv to the one tag? Then it would simply by GoF-Tv easy to see, not complicated for people asking the questions and it divides up the questions between the Novel and the show?

Answer (score -3):

### Yes

A tag for a specific book in the series makes clear that the question is not only about that book, but also likely to be based on the knowledge contained within that book — or the books up until to and including that book.

It helps people who are in the process of reading the series avoid spoilers, and it helps them to find questions they *can* answer.