# Tags for The Expanse book series and TV series

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

*The Expanse* is the name of both a series of novels, and the TV show based on that book series. They both share one tag, [the-expanse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse). Is that OK? Should they be split up? If so, how?

(In addition, the two first books have their own tags that I have proposed to merge into [the-expanse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse); [leviathan-wakes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leviathan-wakes) and [calibans-war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calibans-war), respectively. This should probably only be done if the master tag shouldn't be split, I guess.)

Comment: generally this is fine, as long as the two are largely similar works (same characters, similar plot, etc.) People asking questions can specify if they only care about one or the other. However, we generally like to have tags at the level of individual books in a series so I don't think we need to merge them.

Comment: Note for example http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154157/why-divert-the-missiles is tagged [tv] [the-expanse] - surely not what we want?

Comment: @KateGregory That is what Gallifreyan is suggesting in their answer.

Comment: Tagging this [status-completed] since it's [apparently](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10699/31394) been sorted out (I wasn't part of that operation, but will take Tobias's word for it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Currently policy is generally that [*all* individual works get their own individual tag](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178).** Some exceptions apply, such as films or books of a series (similar to how each episode of The Expanse will not get its own tag). So, there's not a *need* to tag Caliban's War individually, which Gallifreyan's answer also addresses, unless the question is truly about events self-contained within those books or the book itself (such as writing it, behind the scenes, analysis, etc.).

Some pre-existing popular tags, like Harry Potter, do not have a book and film distinction because they have been grandfathered in due to the sheer magnitude of work involved in adjusting the tags. But, in general, we shouldn't penalize a written work because a TV or film version of it happened to be produced without changing the title *Legend of the Seeker* or *Game of Thrones* style.

The general format is the original media gets the plain tag:

[the-expanse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse)

And the same named works in whatever media get the initial year of release appended to the end, so the TV series would be:

[the-expanse-2015](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse-2015)

That is what I would normally recommend doing in case there's already questions about one or the other (or a question about both and [adaptation-comparison](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adaptation-comparison).

However, to make it more clear, I would prefer [the-expanse-novels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse-novels) and [the-expanse-2015](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse-2015) to avoid mistagging show questions with the book tag.

---

In order to accomplish this with the least disruption, we need to:

1. Figure out which questions are about which work (TV vs Books vs Both)
2. Likely get a moderator to rename the tag of the largest group
3. Manually (over time) remove the old and add the new tag to the other group

Comment: Not sure I understood your last paragraph. By "individual works" you don't mean individual books in a book series? Why don't the exceptions for "books of a series" apply in this case?

Comment: @tobiasvl Oh, I misread sec half of your question. Let me update it. Gali's answer is correct on why we don't do individual works in a series, tho.

Comment: _current policy_ - which one?

Comment: @Gallifreyan http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that one. +1 from me!

Comment: Some of the current questions fit within both continuities. I assume the thing to do then is to tag it with both tags then?

Comment: @tobiasvl Yup. If they want to look at differences we have a tag for that, otherwise tagging both lets us know answer can use either for sources.

Comment: @CreationEdge Aight. I was ready to accept this answer as it had 2 upvotes and the other sat at 0, but suddenly they're both at 1 and there's no consensus :o

Comment: @tobiasvl Well, accepted doesn't really matter for this and in a way the policy regarding individual work tags is already in place and highly voted, so we shouldn't be making exceptions on individual basis on accident just because you asked this question for clarification. I'm not terribly certain votes on here matter as much as votes on existing policies.

Comment: OK, so should we just do this now that there's an edit event going on? There are more TV questions than book questions; should we rename [tag:the-expanse] to [tag:the-expanse-2015] and then retag all book questions with [tag:the-expanse-novels] now?

Comment: I've created [tag:the-expanse-novels] and retagged the relevant questions. A mod can probably rename [tag:the-expanse] to [tag:the-expanse-2015] now.

Answer (score 3):

Anything and everything that is both a book and a movie should have separate tags. Neither of which should consist solely of 'the name' of the saga, because the users who are going to misapply tags aren't going to read tag descriptions.

I answered a LotR question once and a commenter's response was, "Who cares about the movies?"

Answer (score 2):

I **don't think we need separate tags** for TV series and the novel series in this particular case.

In case a distinction is needed, askers are free to clarify the medium by supplementing their questions with [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) or [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), respectively.

We should probably add a section to the tag usage guidance, explaining that the appropriate medium tag should be used with [the-expanse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-expanse).

Regarding the merging part, I **don't think this should be done**. According to [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/150018/70236) separate books are more or less self-contained, and could be read separately and out of publication/chronological order. This implies that people might be asking questions related not to the universe in general, as it most often happens with LotR or [ASOIAF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9769/does-a-song-of-ice-and-fire-need-individual-book-tags), but related to specific book.

Comment: Eh… I disagree with the answer you refer to there, and I see that I have upvoted the question's other answer, which also disagrees. Some of the main novels are more self-contained than others (but still can't be read out of order, even if the supplemental short stories can), but the authors have suggested they come in _pairs_, if only thematically, and is like a series of duologies. But fair enough.

Comment: I don't like this. To me that's like SO having [visual-studio] and then [2015] or [2017] for versions. Messes up follow/ignore settings. Just not how tags work.