# Which tag should we use for the film "Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets"?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2239822/) that has been released recently is an adaptation of the [French comic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val%C3%A9rian_and_Laureline). The comic series was already present here, so we have the tag [valerian-and-laureline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valerian-and-laureline).

Our [existing convention](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/70236) states we need a different tag for adaptations; most recent example I can think of is [*The Expanse* novels and the TV series](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10665/70236).

However, the full name of the film will not fit into the 25 character limit (until we get an extension, which seems to be an experiment on other sites now). Which tag should we use for the film? (e.g. [valerian-and-the-city](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valerian-and-the-city), [valerian-2017](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valerian-2017), etc.) Please keep in mind that the tag should be easy to autocomplete (so that it's easy to find), and fit into the character limit, while at the same time looking sane (preferably without awkward abbreviations).

Comment: Even with the new extension to 35 characters, the full name is too long.

Answer (score 11):

Given the extraordinary unlikelihood of a sequel, the absence of other properties called "Valerian" and the need to distinguish it from the comic serials, the tag [valerian-2017](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valerian-2017)  would seem more than adequate.

Note that when searching, the letters "valer" will offer only one other option, so this seems the obvious and simple choice.

Comment: _"extraordinary unlikelihood of a sequel"_ - that bad, huh? :(

Comment: @Gallifreyan - I thought it was quite good. That being said, I appear to be in a small minority.

Comment: @Valorum I am sure someone else on SE also said it's good, so you are not alone ;)

Comment: I was really looking forward to seeing it, but I was put off by all the bad reviews. Since it wasn't universally hated after all maybe I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Erik - The best way I can describe it is that it's like eating a cake made entirely of frosting. There's so much of everything except substance.

Comment: That's a very interesting way to describe a movie. Now I *have* to see the movie so I can see how it stacks up to that description. :)

Comment: Richard also liked "Starship Troopers" The Teenage Romcom, so his judgement is questionable to me. Then again, this movie isn't a remake, a sequel, prequel or midquel. It is therefore by default likely to be better than 90% of lately-made Hollywood stuff.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - Starship Troopers is a masterpiece of unsubtly overstated satire.

Comment: @Valorum - There's a major difference between satire and pastiched caricature.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - Which I've already mentioned.

Answer (score 10):

After the increased tag limit there is chance for a better descriptive tag name and I suggest :

[valerian-city-of-thousand-planets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/valerian-city-of-thousand-planets)